# I can not access phpmyadmin after installing Lampp(XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xampp

Im seeing this error while trying to open phpmyadmin `(http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin) :`

```
`New XAMPP security concept:

 Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.
 This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

 If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

 Error 403
 xser.com
 Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7`
```

Edit:

I have commented out this code in  "httpd-xampp.conf"., but it has introduced a new problem.

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|#server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
        fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
        fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Now Im seeing this --

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

xser.com
Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

Comment: Dont get confused seeing xser.com. I have mapped 127.0.0.1 xser.com in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add this line("Require all granted") to httpd-xampp.conf file at `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">` section.

Here's how the changes will look-

```
# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I tried this method editing the file but I cannot save the file. Any idea on how to change the permissions for `root` user?

Comment: I tried this but still can't access to phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

just type `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp security` 
and set password to your phpmyadmin and log into phpmyadmin as
username - lampp
password - your_given_password

Answer (score 1):

In XAMPP 1.8.1, you have to allow localhost manually by editing `httpd-xampp.conf` file for screenshots visit this [link](http://daksh21ubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/07/new-xampp-security-concept-problem-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

The access is limited with the default config to those ip addresses.

try replacing

```
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
        fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
        fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16
```

with

```
Allow from All
```

Answer (score 0):

- In ubuntu go to

  /opt/lampp/etc/extra (default location)
- Edit httpd-xampp.conf (Need sudo permission to edit)

  ```
  # since XAMPP 1.4.3
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
      AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
      Order allow,deny
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ```
- Restart xampp server